# How to extract print scaling factor from a PDF file in Python?

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I would like to extract the PDF scaling factor programmatically using Python. Specifically, I want to extract the scale factor that appears in the "Fit" under "Print Sizing & Handling" when printing the PDF file.

For example, if the "Fit" dropdown shows a scale of 24%, I want to extract the number 0.24.

I have looked at the PyPDF2 library, but I'm not sure which metadata field contains the print scaling factor. Does anyone know a solutions to this problem? It does not have to use PyPDF2 necessarily.

I have tried to extract the print scaling factor by measuring the dimensions of the PDF page and relating it to the dimension of A4 paper (21.59 by 27.94 in cm), but I'm not sure how to convert these dimensions to a scaling factor. I am almost certain that the output `media_box.getWidth()` or `media_box.getHeight()` is not in cm.

Here's the code I tried:

```py
with open('example.pdf', 'rb') as pdf_file:
    pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
    page = pdf_reader.getPage(0)
    media_box = page.mediaBox
    
    total_width = media_box.getWidth()
    total_height = media_box.getHeight()
    
    # calculate the scaling factor based on the ratio
    scale_factor = (total_width*total_height) / (21.59 * 27.94)
    
    print(scale_factor)
    # returns: 11402.877137305077 (which is clearly wrong)
```

Comment: Even then, that information can be extracted by other methods. For example, information about the operating system can be extracted using the `os` package. Additionally, my case does not pertain to a specific printer. Under the printer, it says `Microsoft Print to PDF`, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to accomplish.

The code below is using the Python Package [pypdf 3.5.2](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/).

My PDF document was formatted for the A4 paper size.

I looked through the `metadata` fields for the PDF and I didn't see any field related to *print scaling factor*.

```
from pypdf import PaperSize, PdfReader

with open('pdf_files/sample_a4.pdf', 'rb') as pdf_file:
    pdf_reader = PdfReader(pdf_file)
    page = pdf_reader.pages[0]

    # these dimension are in points
    page_width = page.mediabox.width
    page_height = page.mediabox.height

    # A4 paper size
    paper_size_format_A4 = PaperSize.A4
    print('A4 paper size in points')
    print(paper_size_format_A4)
    print('\n')
    print('A4 paper size in inches:  8.27 x 11.69')
    print(f'Width size in inches: {page_width / 72}')
    print(f'Height size in inches: {page_height / 72}')
    print('\n')
    print('A4 paper size in points:  595 × 842')
    print(f'Width size in Postscript points: {page_width}')
    print(f'Height size in Postscript points: {page_height}')
    print('\n')
    print('A4 paper size in centimeters:  21 x 29.7')
    print(f'Width size in centimeters: {round(2.54 * page_width / 72, 2)}')
    print(f'Height size in centimeters: {round(2.54 * page_height / 72, 2)}')
    print('\n')
    print('A4 paper size in millimetres:  210 x 297')
    print(f'Width size in millimeters: {round(25.40 * page_width / 72, 2)}')
    print(f'Height size in millimeters: {round(25.40 * page_height / 72, 2)}')
```

Print Output from the code above:

```
A4 paper size in points:
Dimensions(width=595, height=842)


A4 paper size in inches:  8.27 x 11.69
Width size in inches: 8.277777777777779
Height size in inches: 11.694444444444445


A4 paper size in points:  595 × 842
Width size in Postscript points: 596
Height size in Postscript points: 842


A4 paper size in centimeters:  21 x 29.7
Width size in centimeters: 21.03
Height size in centimeters: 29.7


A4 paper size in millimetres:  210 x 297
Width size in millimeters: 210.26
Height size in millimeters: 297.04
```

Here is an example for scaling a PDF to the A4 paper size.

```
from pypdf import PaperSize, PdfReader

with open('pdf_files/sample_a4.pdf', 'rb') as pdf_file:
    pdf_reader = PdfReader(pdf_file)
    page = pdf_reader.pages[0]
    
    # these dimension are in points
    page_width = page.mediabox.width
    page_height = page.mediabox.height

    A4_width = PaperSize.A4.width
    A4_height = PaperSize.A4.height
    
    # resize page to fit *inside* A4
    scale_factor = min(A4_height / page_height, A4_width / page_width)

    print(scale_factor)
    0.9983221476510067
```

If you change the `page_height` and `page_width` to use `centimeters` you will get a scaling factor of '28.292914883499762'

Here is another code example where I reformat the page.

```
from pypdf import PaperSize, PdfReader
from pypdf.generic import RectangleObject

with open('pdf_files/sample_a4.pdf', 'rb') as pdf_file:
    pdf_reader = PdfReader(pdf_file)
    page = pdf_reader.pages[0]

    A4_width = PaperSize.A4.width
    A4_height = PaperSize.A4.height
    page_botton = page.mediabox.bottom
    page_left = page.mediabox.left

    page.mediabox = RectangleObject((page_left, page_botton, A4_width, A4_height))
    page_width = page.mediabox.width
    page_height = page.mediabox.height
    
    A4 paper size in points:  595 × 842
    print(page_width)
    595.0

    print(page_height)
    842.0

    scale_factor = min(A4_height / page_height, A4_width / page_width)
    print(scale_factor)
    1.0
```

The PDF used in the code above was allegedly A4.  The one below is in Letter format 612 x 792.  I use RectangleObject to reformat the page to 595 × 842

```
from pypdf import PaperSize, PdfReader, Transformation
from pypdf.generic import RectangleObject

# A :class:`RectangleObject<pypdf.generic.RectangleObject>`, expressed in
# default user space units, defining the visible region of default user space.
# 
# When the page is displayed or printed, its contents are to be clipped (cropped) 
# to this rectangle and then imposed on the output medium in 
# some implementation-defined manner.  
# Default value: same as :attr:`mediabox<mediabox>`


# input file is a PDF with the format of
# Page size name: Letter
# Inches:  8.5 x 11
# Postscript units: 612 x 792
with open('pdf_files/sample_letter_format.pdf', 'rb') as pdf_file:
    pdf_reader = PdfReader(pdf_file)
    page = pdf_reader.pages[0]

    original_page_width = page.mediabox.width
    print(original_page_width)
    612

    original_page_height = page.mediabox.height
    print(original_page_height)
    792

    original_page_botton = page.mediabox.bottom
    original_page_left = page.mediabox.left

    A4_width = PaperSize.A4.width
    A4_height = PaperSize.A4.height

    page.mediabox = RectangleObject((original_page_left, original_page_botton, A4_width, A4_height))
    new_page_width = page.mediabox.width
    new_page_height = page.mediabox.height

    print(new_page_width)
    595.0

    print(new_page_height)
    842.0

    scale_factor = min(A4_height / original_page_height, A4_width / original_page_width)
    print(scale_factor)
    0.9722222222222222
```

Comment: The output of this code is very close to what I am expecting. I have tried it on three different documents. For three of them, I was expecting `0.24`, `0.24` and `0.26`. The output of this code, to three decimal points are `0.254`, `0.256` and `0.276`, respectively. It seems that they `0.01`away from the expected outcome.This is the closest that I have gotten so far.  
Ultimately, I am trying to combine different pdfs with different scaling factors so when I open them, everything looks coherent, so that one page dose not look zoomed out and the other zoomed in. I want to do it systematically.

Comment: For clarity, I want to combine them with a pdf whose pages have the correct A4 dimensions.

Comment: @Josh so are you planning to combine one PDF  of unknown paper size to another PDF, whose format is A4?

Comment: Exactly! If I get this scaling factor, then I can make the appropriate changes. I can extract this scaling factor manually, but I am hoping to approach it more systematically.

Comment: @Josh take a look at the new section of code.  I have to step away from the keyboard for a bit, once I get back I will see if this code helped.

Comment: Actually it returns `1.0` now for the `scale_factor`. When I check `page.mediabox.bottom` and `page.mediabox.height` they both return `0`, and it seems like `scale_factor` always returns `1.0`. Your previous code works better for now. I think the correct thing to do is to execute `page_width = page.mediabox.width` and `page_height = page.mediabox.height` before `page.mediabox = RectangleObject((page_left, page_botton, A4_width, A4_height))`. In this case, it still returns a `scale_factor` as your previous code, which does not provide an improvement. Might be the best that can be done?!

Comment: I’m not sure if this is the best that we can do. I’m currently away from my development environment, but once I get back I will look at this again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252494/discussion-between-life-is-complex-and-josh).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [documentation](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.0/modules/PaperSize.html), the size is in pixels at 72 ppi. If you are trying to scale use a custom size, you could use the 72 ppi, convert the inches to cm, and then scale from there. However, if you are planning to use a standard size like `A4`, you could just use the dimensions stated in the docs at `A4= Dimensions(width=595, height=842)`.

I can't test it since I don't have the pdf file to test the scaling, but another thing to consider is how you get your scale. If I'm trying to scale a page while maintaining the size ratio, I would probably use the lower scale amount between height and width rather than multiplying them together to divide. This would leave one of them at a smaller size than target, but that can be padded to fit the target size.